# CakePHP odd redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, ssl

There is a CakePHP app. We need it to work over SSL. Because of the (mysterious and apparently secret) way 1&1's Apache is configured, it refuses requests made for files that do not exist properly. Because of this, we turned off pretty permalinks for CakePHP, by uncommenting

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

..in `app/Config/core.php`

Since the app links to itself using pretty permalinks, we needed to redirect from pretty permalinks to non-pretty.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/papers/paper$
RewriteRule (.*) (our domain name)/index.php/papers/paper [R=301,L]
```

However, when accessing a particular page of the app, `/papers/paper`, the server returns a redirect to `/index.php/kunden/homepages/21/d286159521/htdocs/hr/hr.advancedcarellc.com/index.php/papers/paper` for no reason I can figure out. This behavior occurs even when disabling any relevent .htaaccesses.

However, running `grep -r "kunden"` gives

```
./lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:       $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla';
./lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:       $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla/dbhauser/index.php';
./test/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:      $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla';
./test/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:      $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla/dbhauser/index.php';
./test/test/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla';
./test/test/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Network/CakeRequestTest.php:     $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = '/kunden/homepages/4/d181710652/htdocs/joomla/dbhauser/index.php';
```

This seems to imply that the redirect is caused by some sort of absolute path/relative path mismatch, but I can't think of anything actually doing any redirects.

I would also suspect some manner of hidden configuration on 1&1's part. Does anyone have experience with 1&1 and CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with any symlinks?

Sometimes the path returned by the system for a resource can be different to the URL if you make use of symlinks.

Comment: ls -lR . | grep ^l
Run that from the command line when you're in the folder you want to search.